# How would I sum the number of upvotes by specific field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I would like sum the number of upvotes by specific field in mongodb.
For example returning a sum of the number of upvotes author John has gotten.

```
{
"_id": "fc0996a9726e4bf08c3d614afe05c7a8",
"blog_id": "f8da5ae532aa44f6a54d86fd822f7d52",
"author": "John",
"content": "Hello",
"upvotes": 3,
}
{
"_id": "dea0a9713a734717920b652eed268b99",
"blog_id": "f8da5ae532aa44f6a54d86fd822f7d52",
"author": "John",
"content": "Hello",
"upvotes": 2,
}
{
"_id": "3d286c4ce54046f4aac9ea627a48f04e",
"blog_id": "f8da5ae532aa44f6a54d86fd822f7d52",
"author": "John",
"content": "Hello",
"upvotes": 1,
}
{
"_id": "6782b555dd8c47f58dba28e60fda4a5f",
"blog_id": "f8da5ae532aa44f6a54d86fd822f7d52",
"author": "123",
"content": "Bye",
"upvotes": 2,
}
```

How would I sum the upvotes and return a value 6, of the upvotes only John has gotten. 
Also, I am using python for the web app, with flask.

Thank You

Comment: use aggregate with the $match and $sum operator.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$group` of aggregate framework:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{ $group: { _id: { author:'$author'}, totalUpvotes: { $sum: "$upvotes" }}}])
```